# How to display child processes using pstree in C

Tags: c, linux, shell

quick question I was asked about create a program in which one process generates 32 child processes. I created below program(is it correct ?), but do you know how can I using the pstree command, present the tree of these processes ? Appreciate any help.

```
#int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
    {
        if(fork() == 0)
        {
            sleep(5);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
    {
        waitpid(-1, NULL, 0);
    }
    return 0;
}:
```

Comment: Did you read the man page of pstree ? http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pstree.1.html

Comment: Btw, why `waitpid()` in outer separate `for` loop ? You can keep `waitpid()` statement in `else` block of `if`.

Comment: As mentioned by @KillianG. you should take a look at the man page of pstree. Identical processes are grouped together and so if you run pstree with parent process id  you will get output something like this test───32*[test].

Comment: Achal, would you please show how can it be rewrite using else instead of separate for loop ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

For me this works after adding a few `#include` lines, like this:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
  for(int i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
    if(fork() == 0) {
      sleep(30);
      return 0;
    }
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
    waitpid(-1, NULL, 0);
  return 0;
}
```

Then I can compile:

```
gcc pp.c -o myprog
```

which generates the myprog executable. Then I run that, and while it is running I can open another terminal window and run `pstree` there, then it shows the parent process and the 32 child processes, it looks something like this:

```
systemd-+-[...]
        |-[...other stuff...]
        |-systemd-+-(sd-pam)
        |         |-[...other stuff...]
        |         |-gnome-terminal--+-bash---myprog---32*[myprog]
        |         |                 |-bash---pstree
        |         |                 `-4*[{gnome-terminal-}]
        |         |-[...other stuff...]
```

I guess the `bash---myprog---32*[myprog]` part there means that the `myprog` process created 32 child `myprog` processes, so it seems to work as expected.

Comment: Great it works perfectly ! Thank you. Could I ask you for one more favor, to explain me a bit how it those two for loops work together (yes on creation of program I was using external help). I mean the first one is creating new child process using fork(), and put them to sleep() status. After first one is done it comes to second "for" loop and by using waitpid(-1, NULL, 0) -  child process await for status change from -1 to 0, am I right ? Meaning second loop puts "on hold" all child processes created by the first one ?